# How to breakdown MVP designs into testable user stories?

Tags: agile, user-stories, backlog

I am unfamiliar with the ideas behind creating user stories for Agile projects, as well as acceptance criteria.

I was wondering how I could turn any MVP design, like the Basket MVP, into tested user stories.

[image]

What, by my assumption, are below-stories?

- Remove Design
- Update QTY
- Edit Design
- Secure Checkout
- Chat
- Promo Apply
- Product Section

**For each ticket, how to add requirements, for example:**

- What are the interactions on the page (e.g. what happens when you
  click this button?)
- What would different types of users see?
- Are there any validations needed?
- Are there any error messages / edge cases that need to be catered
  for?
- Can we break this ticket into smaller pieces?

Comment: You will likely get a better response to this question in Project Management Stack Exchange https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BarnabyGolden - many thanks, will post that in that site

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the answer to your question is too big to post here.

As well as the pm.stackexchange.com, I suggest buying a book/going on a course.

I could recommend my own but I do not think that is ethical on this forum ;^)